# How to resume an activity?

Tags: android, control-flow

I have 3 activites a, b and c. This is how they work:

```
a->b->c
```

a starts b, b starts c. What I want to do is, I want to resume c from a, if c is running. I don't want to restart c. I cannot just pass an intent, as c needs some extra data in the intent to start again. So is there a way to resume c from a?

Comment: i think you can't resume it from a , because  the activity C is launched from B which is launched from A , so when you click the back Button , the Activity C will be destroyed , and the Activity B will be resumed , when you click the back button again, the acitivity B will be destroyed and A will be resumed , so B and C are already destroyed , and A resumed , in this scenario you  will never be able to resume C from A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resuming c from a means there should be something like: a=>b=>c=>...=>a
in this case:
try:

```
Intent i = new Intent(a, c.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

this will destroy every class after c=>.... and will return to c.

Answer (score 1):

You can bring the activity back to front by using a flag on the intent [FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)

Comment: but it will not be resumed , in his scenario A=>B=>C ,

Comment: if c is already running it will be resumed, if not it will be started. In the scenario a->b->c you never get from a to c directly but maybe he has other flows also, this is what he can use to resume an activity if it is already started.

Comment: @bogdan Will this skip `c`'s `onCreate()` function? Because that's what I need.

Comment: First you should read a bit about this, but basically, if C is already started, only `onResume()` will be called on c. If c was not started before (if it isn't on the back stack), then `onCreate()` will be called because the activity has to be created.

Comment: @bogdan : in the scenario A=>B=>C , the C will be always started from A, because in both case , in the first creation of the Activity A , or in onResume()  the Activity C is alsways already destroyed or even not created yet, @vergil corleone : to skip some code in your `onCreate()` method , just send a boolean extra to your Activity C , and check on that boolean to skip some code or not